# What the algorith should return and how to implement

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, efficiency

I was studying algorithms, and that problem below came up.

Write an efficient algorith that calculates the biggest single positive forward change in value given the values.

[image]

There is a second image with some pseudo code with the resolution, I think. But I couldn't even understand it as well.

[image]

What does the problem mean about single positive forward change? What I can't do based on the requirement?

Comment: How can we possibly know?  Sounds like you should ask whoever set the problem for you.  What's the context where you encountered this?  Can you credit the original source?  Note that we require all copied material to credit the original source: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: How do *valid answers* compare to single out a *best* answer?

Comment: I see @D.W. 
The context was a friend of mine who had to solve that problem for a job. He tried to explain to me but I couldn't understand it... But as you said, maybe there is missing information to fully comprehend it. I don't know the original source, unfortunately.

Comment: @greybeard I don't really know.